# ionic framework service.js returns data before data is loaded from http

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

From my services.js, I am loading some json data using http. But the template is not getting updated at the first load. If I go to some other page and returns I can see the list. It seems to be an asynchronous issue not waiting for the remote data to be populated before the data is returned. Is there anything I can do to prevent return before the asynchronous call is executed? Thanks.

Comment: @MACMAN:   Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally after going through this post http://mcgivery.com/promise-based-architecture-in-an-ionic-app/, i found the solution. I modified the default return statement in the service.js to call it from within the factory function. Modified the controller also. Now I am getting the results ok.